# Columns are getting omitted in dataframe filtering in pandas

Tags: python, dataframe

I an learning the basic modules in python. After using filtering columns with criteria
df_chinese = df[df_all['type of food'] == 'chinese'], the df_chinese is not having the next two columns, even though there is a column with head = city and another column with head = state is there.
Could someone help

```
                   name   category    take_out  rating  \
1     Divya eateries     resturant       True     8   

    stars   type of food         city     state
1    4.5        all             Mumbai     MH

df_chinese = df[df_all['type of food'] == 'chinese']


                   name   category    take_out  rating  \
95     wan ho resturant  resturant       False     6   

    stars  type of food      
95    3        chinese
```

Comment: You slice `df` with `df_all`, is this expected? If not a typo, please provide the definition each each DataFrame.

Comment: df_all is the data frame with all the inofrmation. i wanted to slice a dataframe by filtering the 'type of food ' and to name it as df_chinese.

Comment: I also tried chinese =  df_all['type of food'] == 'chinese'   and then making a new dataframe df_chinese. Still the city and state was getting omitted.

Comment: Then just to try, i changed the order of 'type of food' clolumn to last. but still the city and state was gettign deleted.  I had initially parsed the city and state from differnt excel sheet of a an excel file and merged with the main data. But till here the 'df_all.head(5) was showing all columns.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: To reiterate what @mozway suggested, have you tried `df_chinese = df_all[df_all['type of food'] == 'chinese']`?

Comment: Thank you so much. It worked. They told it the other way in the tutorial.  and I was getting the error.